# How can masking not work in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, mask

I wanted to mask some nodes of my DisplayObject tree. I couldn't make masking work in my big project. So I build a simple example for me and I saw it works actually pretty good. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work in my big project. All my visible objects are Sprites or from classes that extend Sprite.

- masking in big project doesn't work

  - I can see the normal state of my `nodeToBeMasked`
  - when I add the mask to this node I can see the mask
  - but when I set the mask to be the mask, I continue to see everything (pure `nodeToBeMasked` is masked **but not the children** - which would be much more important)
- masking in simple example works fine

**How can masking stop working ?**

---

**Code:** *(that doesn't work, big project)*

```
// custom class extends Sprite
override protected function onAddToStage(event:Event):void 
{
    trace(stage); // stage exists

    var maskSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    maskSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xffff00, 1);
    maskSprite.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 64);
    maskSprite.graphics.endFill();
    maskSprite.x = 64;
    maskSprite.y = 64;

    if (true)
    {
        this.addChild(maskSprite); // doesn't help
        this.mask = maskSprite; // I can see EVERYTHING here, inside and outside the cirle
    }
    else
        addChild(maskSprite); // I can see the mask here
}
```

**Code:** *(that works)*

```
[SWF(frameRate="60",backgroundColor="0xffffff",width="128",height="128")]
public class MaskTest extends Sprite
{
    public function MaskTest()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event: Event): void
    {
        trace(stage);

        // this
        graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 1);
        graphics.drawRect(8, 8, 112, 112);
        graphics.endFill();
        // extra childs <- ^^
        for (var i: int = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var child: Sprite = new Sprite();
            child.graphics.beginFill(uint(Math.random() * 0x1000000), 1);
            child.graphics.drawRect(Math.random() * 64, Math.random() * 64, 64, 64);
            child.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(child);
        }

        // mask
        var maskSprite: Sprite = new Sprite();
        maskSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xffff00, 1);
        maskSprite.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 64);
        maskSprite.graphics.endFill();
        maskSprite.x = 64;
        maskSprite.y = 64;

        // switch to check the mask
        if (true)
            this.mask = maskSprite;
        else
            addChild(maskSprite);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I found out that my custom class *(that is the root and is only responsible for `Event.ENTER_FRAME` updates)* was causing the problem. I don't know why but by disabling the z update in all my project solved the children of my `maskedNode` not being masked.

Comment: Hm, I don't think there is a magical way to tell you the truth. It depends on a lot of things - where you add the mask, what are you trying to mask, etc. First I would NOT try to mask the whole stage. Instead - create some container and mask it. Second, I would try to add objects one by one and see where stuff gets messy.

Comment: @AndreyPopov Just now I try to mask a 2D level that is build out of square blocks 16x16 blocks, 1024x1024 pixels. I add this mask and nothing changes. I still see all the blocks.

Comment: Give gist to this latest test

Comment: Try to make a mask as Shape class.

Comment: Shape class? You mean Sprite? Anyways - try adding just a few simple items on the screen, not everything that you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//`**`this was`**`the problem in my big project`
`maskSprite.z = 0; // avoid this with masks`

**Just a wild guess from me:**
if you use the properties `z`, `rotationX`, `rotationY`, `rotationZ` (maybe some more) the sprite is shifted to the 3D space and the masking is only working in 2D.

*I have experimented with Flash 3D a bit. The transition from 2D to 3D seemed very smooth. You can't see when they "turn".*

Comment: Why you ever wanted to set a zero z property?! :D Anyways, sounds very reasonable to me, having in mind how strange masks are in Flash. Great you've found the problem!

Comment: @AndreyPopov Well, you know on top of all libraries I use for some games I have my own lib that I extend with standard classes that I use very often. And somewhere inside it I had a routine to modify x, y, z automatically with a user defined deltas for movement etc. except the sprite-class is extended and the routine replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The mask MUST be added to the parent to work, not only used as

```
obj.mask = myMask; //This will not work alone
```

To make it work, it must be added to the parent object display list

```
obj.addChild(myMask);
obj.mask = myMask;
```

Comment: No, adding it doesn't help. I tried it before I posted this question and I tried it now.

Comment: @Battle City - it sure *MUST* be added in order to work. Don't know how I've missed that :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov & all The mask [doesn't have to be added](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e0b.html). It **should** but it doesn't have to. I know how to get my masking to work. But I can't find the reason for failed masking (need to reproduce it in my simple example).